# WHERE and WHERE or WHERE Laravel Query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to do a "WHERE AND WHERE OR WHERE" query with laravel, basically what I want to do is get all the events where the user_id equals a certain something AND where type = 'something1' OR 'something2' but right now the event is now only showing for the user_id its for but every user id?

I am trying to get financial events for a specific user:

```
App\Database\Website\Roleplay\Life\LifeEvents::where('user_id', $viewPlayer->id)->where('event_type', 'gained_money')->orWhere('event_type', 'lost_money')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
App\Database\Website\Roleplay\Life\LifeEvents::where('user_id', $viewPlayer->id)
->where(function($where) {
      $where->where('event_type', '=', 'gained_money')
            ->orWhere('event_type', '=', 'lost_money')
});
```

Comment: In your controller: `$events = App\Database\Website\Roleplay\Life\LifeEvents::where('user_id', $viewPlayer->id)->where(function($where) {$where->where('event_type', '=', 'gained_money')->orWhere('event_type', '=', 'lost_money')}); return view('your-view-title')->with(['events' => $events]);` And in your view `@foreach($events as $event)Do whatever you want @endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

```
App\Database\Website\Roleplay\Life\LifeEvents::where('user_id', $viewPlayer->id)
       ->where(function($query) {
              $query->where('event_type', 'gained_money')
              ->orWhere('event_type', 'lost_money'); 
});
```